# Google Firestore Setting Value Fails

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing from a Unity app - it is not an authentication issue as I have tried with an open db and a constrained one. The user is authenticated, I've checked the code at each step and I am seeing the expected values in all of the variables except the raw variable which is set to "{}" whereas initialUser as JSON is {"inventory": [], "saves": []}

```
        private void InitialiseUser(FirebaseUser user, Action<bool> callback) {
        LoadJsonAsset<UserData>("initialise/user", initialUser => {
            if (initialUser != null) {
                userDataRef.SetRawJsonValueAsync(JsonUtility.ToJson(initialUser)).ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {
                    if (task.IsCompleted) {
                        userDataRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(getTask => {
                            var raw = getTask.Result.GetRawJsonValue();
                            userSnapshot = getTask.Result;
                            callback(getTask.IsCompleted);
                        });
                    } else {
                        Debug.LogError("Unable to set initial user data");
                        callback(false);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Debug.LogError("Unable to initialise user");
                callback(false);
            }
        });
    }
```

Reducing the problem so that it is a little clearer:

```
        const string setRaw = "{\"inventory\":[],\"saves\":[]}";

        userDataRef.SetRawJsonValueAsync(setRaw).ContinueWithOnMainThread(setTask => {
            if (setTask.IsCompleted) {
                userDataRef.GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(getTask => {
                    var getRaw = getTask.Result.GetRawJsonValue();

                    Debug.Assert(getRaw == setRaw);
                });
            }
        });
```

What I can see is that getRaw is set to "{}". It seems that if you have members that are empty arrays they are silently stripped out of the stored data and consequently the entire write silently fails.

If for example setRaw is set to "{\"inventory\":[\"test\"],\"saves\":[]}" then we get a saved record.

Comment: I'm having a hard time parsing your question. Which line of the code you shared doesn't do what you expect it to do? What does it do? And what did you expect? Also have a look at [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as there are quite a few methods and variables in the code you shared that we can't know what they do/are.

Answer (score 0):

So having answered my own question, I'll record it here for posterity.

The Firebase.Database.DatabaseReference.SetRawJsonValueAsync method will not write any members that point to an empty array, they are simply skipped and silently fail to be added to the database object. This is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/database/database-reference#class_firebase_1_1_database_1_1_database_reference_1adeb74c29f9619d905e04af20b4aa1e52) which states:

> Set the data at this location to the given string json represenation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Database (as that's how you delete data), but with Firestore you can `IgnoreUndefinedProperties`.

However, I think this must be done from javascript/node, as there is no entry for setting this in Unity.

```
const db = firestore.firestore();
db.settings({ ignoreUndefinedProperties: true })
```